# Count how many elements of an item and return to a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Database where I have a table cars that has some cars, and each devices has a type. I want to make a view to see how many cars of each type I have in the table. What I have till now is, in controller.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CountCars()
    {

        var count = db.Cars.Where(s => s.Cars.Name.Contains("Ford")).Count();


        var view = new CountCarsViewModel()
        {
            Count = count
        };

        return PartialView("_MainSideBarPartialLayout", view);

    }
```

ViewModel class:

```
public class CountCarsViewModel
{

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model  Project.ViewModels.Home.CountCarsViewModel
  <span class="badge">@Model.Count</span>
```

But it wont count any cars.. Just getting 0.

Anyone can help, with a solution?

Comment: Are you sure anything is being matched by your where clause? Debug and see what's being returned. It may be better to move the call to `Count` to a different line, so you can actually see what the query returns in general. It's also suspicious that `Car` would have a `Cars` property on it. In other words, shouldn't your query be `s.Name.Contains(...)`? In that regard, it may be helpful to see your actual entity class  here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query is returning `0` probably because there is no matching Car with Name `Ford` you will have to debug that and see what's happening. To answer  *how many cars of each type I have in the table* you need `GroupBy`:-

```
var view= db.Cars.GroupBy(s => s.Cars.Name)
                   .Select(x => new CountCarsViewModel
                         {
                              CarName = x.Key,
                              Count = x.Count()
                         });
return PartialView("_MainSideBarPartialLayout", view);
```

Change you ViewModel to include a property to hold `CarName` like this:-

```
public class CountCarsViewModel
{
    public string CarName {get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rahul Singh. But it still returns 0..I think you are on the right track. However, all I want is just count how many it is of an item.

Comment: @PerSolbakken - In that case remove `Count()` from `count ` and debug and see are you getting any items, also is the Car exists in `db.Cars`. As far as my answer is concerned it will return each car and number of cars present in table.

Comment: it suddenly worked after i created a new view from CountCars() method. I get the correct count of items. But it just won't work with partialview.. How can I show the counts using partialviews? It works fine with view. Wired..

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is using "PartialView" in "return PartialView("_MainSideBarPartialLayout", view);". Try it on normal view to see the result and then make it partial. If you insist to use partial view , probably you need a trigger for partial view to show correct count.